# java hibernate returns null for new records

Tags: java, hibernate, rabbitmq

I have made a rabbitmq worker in JAVA Hibernate which reads some message and does some job.

The problem I am facing is, if the program is already running and some new record inserted in database through SQLYog or other service, then hibernate never gets that record until I restart my java program.

Here is my code:

```
Campaign campaign = new Campaign().get(message.getInt("campaign_id"));
//do some task
campaign.close();
```

Campaign.java:

```
public class Campaign extends SessionManager {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String subject;
    private String html_template;
    // some more attributes and its getter setter

    public Campaign() {
        super();
    }

    public Campaign get(int id) {
        return (Campaign) session.get(Campaign.class, id);
    }
}
```

SessionManager.java

```
public class SessionManager {
    public Session session = null;

    public SessionManager() {
        if (session == null) {
            SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = sf.openSession();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

My hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="generate_statistics">false</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <mapping resource="Contact.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Campaign.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="SmtpAccount.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: There's a lot of weird things. You create a Campaign just to get one from Hibernate. You open a session but never close it. You're supposed to have an Integer as identifier type but have no attribute of this type.

Comment: Actually I used to close connection, please check my updated code. I was using singleton object, but its not working anymore. Please check my updated code.

Comment: Your code throws a NPE ... You try to close the `Campaign` object returned by Hibernate which has no `session` attribute set ... Because you still haven't fixed the issue: "You create a Campaign just to get one from Hibernate."

Comment: Campaign inherits SessionManager, and SessionManager has session attribute.

Comment: Oups, doesn't catch you're doing init in constructor. Very ugly design. You still don't close session opened for first created campaign. Furthermore, Hibernate may use reflection or may use `Unsafe` ([The infamous sun.misc.Unsafe explained](http://mydailyjava.blogspot.fr/2013/12/sunmiscunsafe.html)) which omits instance initialization.

Comment: Have you check that you retrieve correct identifier from your message ?

Comment: Ok I found the problem, I need to create stateless session, thanks to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313623/java-hibernate-does-not-see-changes-in-database We both had same problem